# Copy files from one DV server to another PHP

Tags: php, file-io, remote-server

But what's the best and easiest way to copy a file or folder between a local and remote server using php? These are files located above the web folder, so I'll need to use paths instead of the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dedicated virtual server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using PHP's built-in FTP functions.

**EDIT:**  Ahh, you want secure.  This is what I would use then: [SSH2-SFTP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

Comment: Is that secure?  How would I do that with SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

Well i made this function hope it works for you copy files from ftp:
    $ftpConnection = the conection, example ftp_connect(1.0.0.1).
    $path = the ftp path.
    $destination = the local file.

```
function ftpRecursiveFileListing($ftpConnection, $path, $destination) {
    $contents = ftp_nlist($ftpConnection, $path);
    foreach ($contents as $currentFile) {
        if (strpos($currentFile, '.') === false) {
            $dir = basename($currentFile);
            echo "<br> <b> Directorio </b>" . $dir;
            mkdir($destination . "/" . $dir);
            ftpRecursiveFileListing($ftpConnection, $currentFile, $destination . "/" .   $dir);
        } else {
            $file = basename($currentFile);
            echo '<br> <b>archivo </b>' . $file;
            echo '<br> <b>path </b>' . $path;
            echo '<br> <b>completo </b>' . $path . "/" . $file;
            ftp_get($ftpConnection, $destination . '/' . $file, $path . '/' . $file, FTP_BINARY);
        }
    }
}
```